# Regex matching not containing specific URL parameter

Tags: regex, url, squid

I need a regex to match all URLs which does not contain specific URL parameter, for example if I make *except=yes* as an exception:

```
www.example.com  MATCH
www.example.com/  MATCH
www.example.com/?except=yes NOT MATCH
www.example.com/?test=true&except=yes NOT MATCH
www.example.com/?test=true&except=yes&foo=bar NOT MATCH
www.example.com/foo/bar/?except=yes NOT MATCH
www.example.com/?test=true&except=yesyes&foo=bar MATCH
```

The parameter should be exactly same but ignoring cases, I can achieve some points using negative look ahead but I cannot meet the requirement of last example.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `/^((?!except=yes).)*$/`. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) for further details.

```
2.0.0-p648 :009 > regex = /^((?!except=yes).)*$/
 => /^((?!except=yes).)*$/ 
2.0.0-p648 :010 > "www.example.com".match regex
 => #<MatchData "www.example.com" 1:"m"> 
2.0.0-p648 :011 > "www.example.com/".match regex
 => #<MatchData "www.example.com/" 1:"/"> 
2.0.0-p648 :012 > "www.example.com/?except=yes".match regex
 => nil 
2.0.0-p648 :013 > "www.example.com/?test=true&except=yes".match regex
 => nil 
2.0.0-p648 :014 > "www.example.com/?test=true&except=yes&foo=bar".match regex
 => nil 
2.0.0-p648 :015 > "www.example.com/foo/bar/?except=yes".match regex
 => nil 
2.0.0-p648 :016 > "www.example.com/?test=true&except=yesyes&foo=bar".match regex
 => nil
```

**Edit**

In order to match the last string(which contains `except=yesyes`), use the following regex. `/^((?!except=yes\b).)*$/` The only difference is `\b`, which matches word boundary such as whitespace, punctuations.

```
> /^((?!except=yes\b).)*$/.match "www.example.com"
 => #<MatchData "www.example.com" 1:"m"> 
> /^((?!except=yes\b).)*$/.match "www.example.com/"
 => #<MatchData "www.example.com/" 1:"/"> 
> /^((?!except=yes\b).)*$/.match "www.example.com/?except=yes"
 => nil 
> /^((?!except=yes\b).)*$/.match "www.example.com/?test=true&except=yes"
 => nil 
> /^((?!except=yes\b).)*$/.match "www.example.com/?test=true&except=yes&foo=bar"
 => nil 
> /^((?!except=yes\b).)*$/.match "www.example.com/foo/bar/?except=yes"
 => nil 
> /^((?!except=yes\b).)*$/.match "www.example.com/?test=true&except=yesyes&foo=bar"
 => #<MatchData "www.example.com/?test=true&except=yesyes&foo=bar" 1:"r">
```

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry I made a mistake, the last example should be `MATCH` since _except_ not fully equals to _yes_